# React Native get stuck in Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.appname/.MainActivity }

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an issue building a React Native app, recently I upgraded from react-native 0.72.x to 0.73.x.

For the migration I followed the steps in [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.72.8&to=0.73.1)

After that, compilation on iOS runs flawless, but when I try to run on Android the application gets stuck showing this message:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.appname/.MainActivity }
```

On the device the splash screen is showing, but after a while, the application crashes.

This is an extract of the logcat that is repeating when the app gets stuck:

```
01-07 14:46:47.753  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1124)
01-07 14:46:47.753  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=47642, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10142 RequestorUid: 10142 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.dialer UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.753  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1112)
01-07 14:46:47.754  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=47644, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10142 RequestorUid: 10142 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.dialer UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.754  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1124)
01-07 14:46:47.754  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=47840, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10142 RequestorUid: 10142 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.dialer UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.754  5124  6006 I BugleRcsEngine: [58] bzmg.c: Connected state: [1], networkType: [WIFI]
01-07 14:46:47.755  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1128)
01-07 14:46:47.755  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49346, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10170 RequestorUid: 10170 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.youtube UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.755  5124  6451 I BugleRcsEngine: [65] cagd.handleMessage: RcsEngineImpl[DUAL_REG]:[f0d7170a-fe15]>Handler: handleMessage processing message:[NOTIFY_UPTIME_IGNORE_STATE_CHANGED] with [non-null]:RcsEngineImpl reference
01-07 14:46:47.755  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1116)
01-07 14:46:47.755  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=49348, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10170 RequestorUid: 10170 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.youtube UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.755  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1128)
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49349, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10170 RequestorUid: 10170 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.youtube UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1128)
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49351, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10170 RequestorUid: 10170 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.youtube UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.756  5124  6451 W BugleRcsEngine: [65] caxf.h: Cannot use CS.apk as it's battery optimized
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1128)
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49354, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10170 RequestorUid: 10170 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.youtube UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1112)
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49367, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10251 RequestorUid: 10251 RequestorPkg: com.twitter.android UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1112)
01-07 14:46:47.756  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49369, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10251 RequestorUid: 10251 RequestorPkg: com.twitter.android UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.757  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1128)
01-07 14:46:47.757  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49429, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10193 RequestorUid: 10193 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.contacts UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.757  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1116)
01-07 14:46:47.757  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=49431, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10193 RequestorUid: 10193 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.contacts UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.759  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1128)
01-07 14:46:47.759  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=49800, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10170 RequestorUid: 10170 RequestorPkg: com.google.android.youtube UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.759  1796  3265 D InstantWifi: Receive Wifi is connected, freq =  5240 and currentNetworkId : 80, wifiinfo = SSID: <unknown ssid>, BSSID: 02:00:00:00:00:00, MAC: 02:00:00:00:00:00, IP: /192.168.1.22, Security type: 2, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, Wi-Fi standard: 5, RSSI: -57, Link speed: 866Mbps, Tx Link speed: 866Mbps, Max Supported Tx Link speed: 866Mbps, Rx Link speed: 780Mbps, Max Supported Rx Link speed: 866Mbps, Frequency: 5240MHz, Net ID: -1, Metered hint: false, score: 60, isUsable: true, CarrierMerged: false, SubscriptionId: -1, IsPrimary: 1, Trusted: true, Restricted: false, Ephemeral: false, OEM paid: false, OEM private: false, OSU AP: false, FQDN: <none>, Provider friendly name: <none>, Requesting package name: <none><none>MLO Information: , Is TID-To-Link negotiation supported by the AP: false, AP MLD Address: <none>, AP MLO Link Id: <none>, AP MLO Affiliated links: <none>
01-07 14:46:47.760  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1100)
01-07 14:46:47.760  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=50112, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10255 RequestorUid: 10255 RequestorPkg: com.bbva.GEMA UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.761  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1088)
01-07 14:46:47.761  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=50114, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10255 RequestorUid: 10255 RequestorPkg: com.bbva.GEMA UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.761  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1116)
01-07 14:46:47.761  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=50118, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10315 RequestorUid: 10315 RequestorPkg: com.bancomer.mbanking UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.761  1796  3238 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1104)
01-07 14:46:47.761  1796  3238 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=50120, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10315 RequestorUid: 10315 RequestorPkg: com.bancomer.mbanking UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
01-07 14:46:47.764  8943  8971 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
01-07 14:46:47.764  8943  8971 W .gms.persistent: Large reply transaction of 1056768 bytes, interface descriptor , code 1
01-07 14:46:47.766  1796  3238 D ConnectivityService: NetReassign [no changes] [c 1] [a 0] [i 3]
01-07 14:46:47.772  5124  6451 I BugleRcsEngine: [65] cado.E: ProvisioningEngineDataRetriever: Rcs is enabled from user settings: true
```

Can anyone help me to understand what's happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share crash log?

Comment: Updated the question with an extract of the logcat when the application get stuck.